# Spectrum of reduced von Neumann algebra

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $e$ a projector.
Do you know if $Spec_{eMe}(exe)\subset Spec_M(x)$ for $x\in M$?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No. Given any positive contraction $c$, the $2\times 2$ matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} c& (c-c^2)^{1/2}\\ (c-c^2)^{1/2}&1-c\end{bmatrix}
$$
is a projection. This allows you to construct $x$ and $e$ such that $\sigma_M(x)=\{0,1\}$ but $\sigma_{eMe}(exe)$ can be any closed subset of the unit interval.

Similarly, if $v$ is a contraction,
$$
\begin{bmatrix} v& (1-vv^*)^{1/2}\\ (1-v^*v)^{1/2}&v^*\end{bmatrix}
$$
is a unitary. So in this case $\sigma_M(x)$ is in the unit circle, while $\sigma_{eMe}(exe)$ can be any closed subset of the closed unit disk.

Comment: $exe$ is positive in $eMe$ isn’t it?

Comment: Yes. Interval, not ball. Edited.